# Are there user-related tables when I use "Work or School Accounts" authentication in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating new ASP.NET Project. I selected "Work or School Accounts" authentication which I want to use with Azure AD. So are there users-related tables like **AspNetUsers** or **AspNetRoles**? Because I don't see anything in Models folder.

Comment: if the accounts are stored in Azure AD then why would there need to be anything in your database?

Comment: I asked because I am trying to figure out how to do relationship between users and other tables as it's the first time I do Azure AD authentication. I think I got it now.

Comment: If you need to assign some data to a user within your database, you can still put their username into a column in your own tables...you just don't need to make a relationship between them and another table.