# How to access user data with work and school accounts in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am building a simple `CRUD` application in `ASP.NET MVC`. While setting up the project, I have selected `Authentication` to be `Work and School Accounts` so that the employees in the company can access the application with their `Office 365` accounts.

Now, the issues that I am facing is, I need to track/maintain history of the changes that were made (Creating, Updating, or Deleting) and who made them. For that, I plan to keep track using the user's email ID, or name, or ID (if possible).  But, since I do not have the `Users` data with me in the project, how can I do this? I have worked on `ASP.NET MVC` before, but working with `Work and School Accounts` authentication is a first for me.

I found a similar question in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56886282/are-there-user-related-tables-when-i-use-work-or-school-accounts-authenticatio). But this question did not have any answer. There were comments which were talking about adding username into a table in the project, but I was unsure of how to do that.

Comment: Do you want to authenticate with Microsoft? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/authentication-oauth?view=bingads-13 Im not sure if its can help you

Comment: I have gone through this. Thank you for the link. It is touch and go. I am not sure if I can implement this.